# Does modifying a stored procedure just update the stored procedure definition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to modify a stored procedure, and I wanted to get some insight on what "modifying" a stored procedure actually does. I have a stored procedure, and in it is a statement like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[get_orders]
    INSERT INTO customer (id, date, name) 
    VALUES(@id, getdate(), @name)

    SELECT
    full_id,
    fname,
    lname,
    ...
    FROM orders
```

If I modify this stored procedure (right click the sp in SSMS, and select "Modify") by adding a column to the Select statement for example, and then click "Execute" (or press F5), will this just update the stored procedure definition, or will it also "run" the code in it, for example, run the "INSERT" statement (or if there was a "DELETE") and actually do some inserting (or deleting)?

I'm assuming that it will just update the stored procedure, and not actually run the queries in it, but I just want to be sure. Sorry if this question seems basic, but I couldn't easily find an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're changing the "guts" of the procedure.  But permissions stay the same.  If you drop/re-add, you'll lose permissions that were originally with it.  That's the 2 cent version.

Comment: If you change the "signature" (the arguments), that could be a motzah ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `alter` the definition of the stored procedure that is all that you're doing — altering the definition/code inside said procedure. It is not going to `execute` the procedure, to do so you'll need to `exec` your procedure after it has been `alter`ed.

Answer (score 1):

if you execute on that statement it should only store the procedure changes.

When you find your procedure in the explorer then hit execute it will then run the procedure.